# Convert Flash to iOS app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

For the record, I am an iOS developer, and have absolutely no background on how flash programs work/run/developed...etc.

I have a Flash program that is mostly a collection of SWF files. It does, however, contain some Actionscript, Javascript and other integrated languages here and there..

I would like to convert this project/program to an iPad application. Is it possible?

***What I got from searching the net:***

- Converting Actionscript to LUA script
- Using Corona SDK to port the program to iOS
- Starting a new iOS project in flash and moving the code somehow..
- Other tedious ways which are not feasible at all....

The above mostly handles the actionscript part .. what about the SWF files?

*As a last resort, one could at least guide me to a developer/company who can handle this task, or provide training to accomplish this.*

**Additional details**
The flash program app file is already generated, and the program works on desktops perfectly. The program is somehow an interactive e-book, and it has some linked XML files to index the table of contents and other sections...

Comment: Hey Mazyod!  I'm not sure if you are still on this project, but I recently needed something similar.  I ended up making the [SwiffCore framework](https://github.com/musictheory/SwiffCore) to render .swf shapes and animations using CoreGraphics and Core Animation.

Comment: Wow, that's really cool! Should come in handy one day. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not done a lot of iOS development yet, but here are my experiences so far; maybe they help you form a better idea.

- Only the main SWF can contain actionscript code.
- I'm not sure how far assets (Sounds, Fonts, MovieClips) in other SWFs which are exported for actionscript are accessible to the main SWF.
- It is possible to include additional XML files (and other types) which can be loaded via the normal loader classes.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I came acrosshe tool which allows you to convert and play swf to some cross-platform frameworks. Now they support only Cocos2d-x, Unity 3d and Starling. But I saw the logo of Corona on their homepage. You can go there and ask them. I don't remember the right name of the site, but tool is called GAF converter